# Confused about python modules and functions in it

Tags: python

To describe my questions concisely, please have a look at examples below:

1. Module `os` have a function `getcwd()` which returns current working directory. But there are no details about `os.getcwd()` in `/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py` file. Where is the implementation of the function?
2. `os.path` is also a module in python , but in `/usr/lib/python2.7` directory, there is no file named `os.path`. So when you `import os.path` in your python script, which file is imported?

Thank all your helps...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 . The getcwd() functions is implemented in C look [here](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Modules/posixmodule.c?view=markup).

2 . `os.path` is defined in the module [os](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/os.py?view=markup) by dynamically detecting the os type and importing the correspondent library and set in it using : `sys.modules['os.path'] = path`

Answer (score 2):

Modules do not have to be python scripts. Using the [C-API](http://docs.python.org/c-api/) you can write [modules in C or C++](http://docs.python.org/extending/index.html#extending-index). You can compile them as dynamic libraries, so that the interpreter can load them dynamically, or you can recompile the interpreter and link the modules into it.

Comment: ... and in Jython, modules are installed as `.class` files. I guess IronPython does something similar.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a POSIX system (Linux, Mac OS X), these lines in os.py bring in those bits:

```
from posix import *
import posixpath as path
```

And on Windows:

```
from nt import *
import ntpath as path
```

(Plus a couple more options for less popular systems)

Note that using `from x import *` is usually frowned on. This is kind of a special case.

Answer (score 1):

The interactive python shell can be used to check where a module is loaded from, and to see if a method is built-in or python:

```
>>> import os
>>> os
<module 'os' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/os.pyc'>
>>> os.path
<module 'posixpath' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/posixpath.pyc'>
>>> os.getcwd
<built-in function getcwd>
>>> os.path.join
<function join at 0x87d1b1c>
>>>
```

`os.path` is loaded from `posixpath.pyc`,
`os.getcwd` is built-in, `os.path.join` is a python method.